# Simple Startup Script Not Behaving

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu-mate

So I have a small script that is supposed to launch two terminal windows upon startup. I have added it to the startup applications and it is sitting in `~/.local/bin` which exists in my `$PATH`. Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 5 &&

mate-terminal --geometry=87x47+0+0
mate-terminal --geometry=87x47+802+0
```

Now when I run it from an existing terminal or via <kbd>Alt+F2</kbd> (Ubuntu Mate) it works properly (although the vertical dimensions do not go above 46 despite an input of 47). I would like it to "snap lock" between my top and bottom panels but it is close enough for now.

My main concern is that when I reboot, only the first window launches. The second window launches only after I have closed the first. Would it work if I were to send the first window to the background by adding a `&`?

Answer (score 2):

You script is basically this:

```
sleep 5 && mate-terminal --geometry=87x47+0+0
mate-terminal --geometry=87x47+802+0
```

This means "wait five seconds, then launch the terminal, when that's done, launch the second terminal".  "Done" here means the terminal have exited and given back control to the script.

What you probably want is

```
sleep 5
xtoolwait mate-terminal --geometry=87x47+0+0
xtoolwait mate-terminal --geometry=87x47+802+0
```

`xtoolwait` will return control to the rest of the script as soon as the X client that it is launching (the terminal) has mapped its window.

`xtoolwait` should be installed with your X server software, but if it's not, it ought to be available as a package from your ordinary distribution.

Failing that (it seems to have been removed as a Debian and Ubuntu package), you may use

```
sleep 5
mate-terminal --geometry=87x47+0+0 &
mate-terminal --geometry=87x47+802+0 &
```

to just start the terminals as background processes as you yourself suggested.

---

When I last cared about where on my desktop things appeared, some 15+ years ago, `xtoolwait` was part of the standard X11 distribution, if I remember correctly. Since then I've taken to running one application per virtual desktop, and rarely use anything other than a terminal with `tmux` and a browser.

I'm slightly surprised to see that `xtoolwait` is no longer part of the standard X11 package, but I assume the world will go on without it.

Just use `&` at the end of the commands.